# Do you know of any NPAPI Chrome plugin that plays local media and communicates with a web app?

Tags: browser, npapi, browser-plugin

Need some inspiration for such a plugin. We aim to mix media, stored locally and in the cloud, in one online experience. Access via the File API sucks badly. We need something better.

Answer (score 0):

Sure... Flash does that, Silverlight does that, Quicktime does that, Move Media Player does that...  I'm sure there are others, but I'm not sure how it helps you, since none that I am aware of except VLC is open source, and the VLC open source plugin isn't the best written one I have seen (no offense to those involved, it's a hard task).

If you haven't already, I'd take a look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org); it simplifies the plugin creation process and lets you focus more on what you want to do with it.